# How to Abstract away the Response object in MVC4 for Testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have certain controller actions in my MVC4 web application that use the Response object to access query string variables, among other things. What's the best practice for abstracting that away so it doesn't interfere with unit testing the actions?

Comment: Side note: consider if you can simply have all necessary query parameters as arguments of an action... than your testing would be much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MVC4 team have made `HttpContext` related properties abstract so that they can be mocked, so `Response` is now of type `HttpResponseBase` so has already been abstracted away. You can just mock calls to it.

Below is a standard method that I've used in the past to initialise my controllers in a unit test scenario. It's with respect to MOQ. I create a fake http context that mocks out the various related properties as required. You can modify this to fit your exact scenario.

After instantiating the controller I pass it to this method (perhaps in a base class - I use NBehave for my unit testing but I won't muddy the waters with anything related to that specifically here):

```
protected void InitialiseController(T controller, NameValueCollection collection, params string[] routePaths)
{
    Controller = controller;
    var routes = new RouteCollection();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);
    var httpContext = ContextHelper.FakeHttpContext(RelativePath, AbsolutePath, routePaths);
    var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), Controller);
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), routes);
    Controller.ControllerContext = context;
    Controller.ValueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(collection, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Controller.Url = urlHelper;
}
```

The `ContextHelper` is where the mocks are all set up:

```
public static class ContextHelper
{
    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext(string relativePath, string absolutePath, params string[] routePaths)
    {
        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();

        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        response.Setup(x => x.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
        httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost:300"));
        httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request.UserHostAddress).Returns("127.0.0.1");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(relativePath))
        {
            server.Setup(x => x.MapPath(relativePath)).Returns(absolutePath);
        }

        // used for matching routes within calls to Url.Action
        foreach (var path in routePaths)
        {
            var localPath = path;
            response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(localPath)).Returns(localPath);
        }

        var writer = new StringWriter();
        var wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest("", "", "", "", writer);
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(wr);
        return httpContext.Object;
    }
}
```

I've recently written a blog post covering this approach but using `Nsubstitute` as the mocking framework instead of `MOQ`:

[Unit testing Controllers using NUnit and NSubstitute](http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/unit-testing-controllers-using-nunit-and-nsubstitute)

Comment: Can you show some code with an action that uses the response object, and a test that mocks it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code snippets that you should find useful

Comment: This is really helpful! I have a couple questions:

What do you pass into the Init method for the collection? What is it a collection of? 

What should the routePaths be? 

What should the relative and absolute paths generally be (in the same method)?

Comment: As I said, you can adapt this to your own ends, so some of those parameters may not be useful for you. If you don't need `Server.MapPath` you can get rid of `relativePath` and `absolutePath`. For the collection, you can just pass in a `new FormCollection()` unless you need to set a form up within your action. You might find it helpful to scale it right back and just mock the things you need, adding in extra parts as tests fail because of calls happening within the MVC framework.